# Extra fields printed from appengine-mapreduce python demo

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

As I was playing around with appengine-mapreduce found on http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/, I managed to deploy everything successfully using the python demo.

While testing the application by uploading a simple text file all zipped up, I found the output to contain parameters such as "apple", "attr", "x", "com", "y", "mac", "os", "text encoding", "utf", "y".

It looks like its also printing out the specifications of the machine I'm using.

Any idea 
1) What this is? 
2) How to get rid of it?

Thanks!